# How to get a list of file paths in a specific folder in Spring app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, filepath

I need a list of files' paths in a specific folder. I want it to work after the app is packed into a jar, so using a `File` object might not work.

The paths need to start with a static folder, so for example:

```
/static/json/networks/network.json
```

So far, I've tried this:

```
File folder = new File("src/main/resources/static/json/networks/pools");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
```

But it gives me a list of paths starting with:

```
/src/main/resources/static/etc
```

Which I won't be able to use with a ClassPathResource. I have also tried:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = MethodHandles.lookup().getClass().getClassLoader();
PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver(classLoader);
```

But that gives me an absolute path to the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give a try to a library called [maven-shared-utils](https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-shared-utils/index.html) (check the class DirectoryScanner) .

Or you can do it yourself :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);

    final String baseFolder = "folder1";
    try {
    Path pathBase = Paths.get(ClassLoader.getSystemResource(baseFolder).toURI());

        Files.walk(pathBase.resolve("folder2/folder3"))
                .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                .forEach(f -> System.out.println(pathBase.relativize(Paths.get(f.toUri()))));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

 }}
```

this code will print for the files in `src/main/resouces/folder1/folder2/folder3/*`:

folder2/folder3/fil2.json

folder2/folder3/file3.kt

folder2/folder3/file1.xml

Comment: As far as I'd love to check it, I'm not familiar with Java 8 yet. How do I access the list? :f